# Replace the string value with value in the find list in R

Tags: r, replace, gsub, qdap

I have a dataset that has a column like

```
   string<-c('lib1_Rstudio_case1','lib2_Rstudio_case1and2','lib5_python_notthe correct_language','lib3_Jupyter_really_good','lib1_spyder_nice','lib1_R_the_core')
   replacement<-c('Rstudio','Jupyter','spyder','R')
```

I want to replace the string value id they match the value in replacement. I am using the following code right now

```
gsub(paste(replacement, collapse = "|"), replacement = replacement, x = string)
```

This in another piece of code which i am using to find the cases

```
string[grepl(paste(replacement, collapse='|'), string, ignore.case=TRUE)]
```

I want to update the ones that I find 
I want the output to be like

```
Rstudio,Rstudio,'',Jupyter,spyder,R
```

I don't want to do it by hard coding it. I want to write a code that is scalable.

Any help is really appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: Try `ifelse((x <- sub('.*_', '', string)) %in% replacement, x, '')`

Comment: This code words for me but I can not replace anything 

  grep(paste(replacement, collapse='|'), string, ignore.case=TRUE)]

Comment: Sorry for that. I will try to edit the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This another simple code I used. That doesn't need the regex function.Thanks for the help

```
string<-c('lib1_Rstudio_case1','lib2_Rstudio_case1and2','lib5_python_notthe correct_language','lib3_Jupyter_really_good','lib1_spyder_nice','lib1_R_the_core')
replacement<-c('R','Jupyter','spyder','Rstudio')
replaced=string
replaced=''


for (i in 1:length(replacement))
{
  replaced[which(grepl(replacement[i],string))]=replacement[i]
}
replaced[is.na(replaced)]=''
```

Answer (score 1):

isolate `id` using `gsub` function and then find `id` that is not matching the length of `replacement` by means of `is.na` function. Then replace the identified id with empty character `''`.

**EDIT:** Since you changed the string data in the question, I modified the `gsub` function. The pattern used in `gsub` function will find the numeric value right after `lib` text and omit the remaining part of the string element.

```
replacement<-c('Rstudio','Jupyter','spyder','R')

string<-c('lib1_Rstudio','lib2_Rstudio','lib5_python','lib3_Jupyter','lib1_spyder','lib1_R')
index <- is.na( replacement[ as.integer( gsub( "lib([[:digit:]])*[[:alnum:]_\ ]*", "\\1", string)) ] )
a1 <- sapply( strsplit(string, "_"), function( x ) x[2] )
a1[ index ] <- ''
a1
# [1] "Rstudio" "Rstudio" ""        "Jupyter" "spyder"  "R"    

string <- c('lib1_Rstudio_case1','lib2_Rstudio_case1and2','lib5_python_notthe correct_language','lib3_Jupyter_really_good','lib1_spyder_nice','lib1_R_the_core')
index <- is.na( replacement[ as.integer( gsub( "lib([[:digit:]])*[[:alnum:]_\ ]*", "\\1", string)) ] )
a1 <- sapply( strsplit(string, "_"), function( x ) x[2] )
a1[ index ] <- ''
a1
# [1] "Rstudio" "Rstudio" ""        "Jupyter" "spyder"  "R"
```

Comment: I changed the rank of string, like `string<-c('lib1_Rstudio','lib2_python','lib5_Rstudio','lib3_Jupyter','lib1_spyder','lib1_R')`, and return wrong result `"Rstudio" "python"  ""        "Jupyter" "spyder"  "R" `. Could you tell me why it is wrong?

Comment: The id 5 is greater than the length of `replacement` which is the reason for the third element `lib5_Rstudio` turned to `''` empty character

Comment: The length of `replacement` is 4, because there are 4 elements in this character vector - `replacement`

Comment: Thanks for your explain.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation