# Replace string values in a list with similar values R

Tags: r, string

This question is related to  [Replace the string value with value in the find list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684589/replace-the-string-value-with-value-in-the-find-list-in-r).  However my string and replacement vectors have similar characters:

```
replacement = c("10deg AC45", "10deg TA45", "15deg AC45", "AC45", "TA45")
string = c("10deg - 02 AC45", ""10deg -05 AC45" , "10deg-02 AC45", "10deg-05 TA45", "15deg-10 AC45", "AC45-10", "TA45-1")
```

Hence trying:

```
replaced=string
replaced=''


for (i in 1:length(replacement))
{
  replaced[which(grepl(replacement[i],string))]=replacement[i]
}
replaced[is.na(replaced)]=''
```

Results in:

```
[1] "AC45", "AC45", "AC45" "TA45" "AC45" "AC45" "TA45"
```

Rather than:

"10deg AC45","10deg AC45", "10deg AC45", "10deg TA45", "15deg AC45", "AC45", "TA45"

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I assume that the order of `replacement` and `string` is not always the same? Also, can they be of different lengths?

Comment: Thanks. Order is definitely not the same.  The string has values with or without hyphen and sometimes extra spaces:

10deg-02AC45

10deg -02 AC45

10deg -02AC45

I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry if this is against SO procedure but might it not be possible to clean `string` rather than going down the replacement route? If the issue is always hyphens and digits like the examples in the comment above it wouldn't be too difficult. In your linked question the task was a lot trickier as `string` and `replacement` were **very** different.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I will try just to clean it, deleting everything after hyphens.

Comment: Sure, the following 3 lines should do the trick: `string <- gsub(" ", "", string)` `string <- gsub("-\\d{1,2}", "", string)` `string <- gsub("deg", "deg ", string)`

Comment: That is spot on. Thanks so much!